# Python parse element

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm want to parse some info from the page, but have some troubles, becouse i cant parse something without id or class.
Now i have tag div with image inside and some text (numbers) i need to get this numbers, but this div have only style tag and i cant use this style tag coz he always changing.

I have something like game site auction and trying to parse name of the item, price and link.
But now i can get only names.

im trying to find all 'a' for div with father class.
im trying to find hrefs
im trying to find by style

```
def rshp_parse (base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', class_={'shop-search-row'})
        for div in divs:
            title = div.find('span').text
            price = div.find('div')
            href = div.find('a', class_={'champions_container'})['href']
            # href = soup.find('div', style='color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none')
```

HTML

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:15%;line-height:50px;vertical-align:top;white-space: nowrap;">
            <img src="/assets/rpc/shard.png" style="width:20px">35,000
        </div>
```

35,000 - its what im needed

```
<a href="/market/auction/1227124" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none">
```

and this link

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: [link](https://www.roshpit.ca/market/browse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconstruct "table" as follows. With the dataframe you can use usual pandas syntax to access any element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

r = requests.get('https://www.roshpit.ca/market/browse')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = []

for row in soup.select('.shop-search-row'):
    name = row.select_one('.item_image + span').text
    seller = row.select_one('div:nth-child(3)').text.strip()
    bid = row.select_one('div:nth-child(4)').text.strip()
    buyout = row.select_one('div:nth-child(5)').text.strip()
    ends = row.select_one('div:nth-child(6)').text.strip()
    listing = [name, seller, bid, buyout, ends]
    results.append(listing)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['name', 'seller' , 'bid' , 'buyout' , 'ends'])
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df.buyout = df.buyout.str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df[df['name'].str.contains("Hammer") & (df["buyout"] < 50000)]
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! 
Now im stuck a little, trying to searching in dataframe with two columns at once. ```df[df['name'].str.match('Raijin')]``` 
and i want a second like buyout <=50

Comment: Remember to also check columns types. You may need to do conversions as read in from strings.

Comment: yeah, im understand, what im trying to do:

```df[['bid', 'buyout']] = df[['bid', 'buyout']].apply(pd.to_numeric)```
but have an error:
```ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "50,000" at position 15', 'occurred at index bid')```